# Sending templates with PHPMailer and Mandrill

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, phpmailer, mandrill

I've made a script using PHPMailer that sends email using Mandrill. I am trying to send a html template that is made with bootstrap, but when the mail comes, the CSS doesn't work.
I tried to get the html content with `file_get_contents()` function but it doesn't get the bootstrap stylesheet. Any ideas?

Here is the script

```
<?php
        include "../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

        include "../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";

        error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);


        if (!isset($_POST['Submit']) |$_POST['Submit'] != 'Trimite') {

                $adress = '';

        } else {

        $adress = $_POST['adress'];

        $mail   = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();

        $mail->Host     = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';

        $mail->Port     = 587;

        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

        $mail->Username = 'username';

        $mail->Password = 'key';

        $mail->SMTPSecure       = 'tsl';

//      $mail->SMTPDebug        = 1;

        $mail->From     = 'email@example.com';

        $mail->FromName = 'Name';

        $mail->AddAddress($adress);

        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        $mail->Subject = 'Subject';
        $mail->Body    = file_get_contents( 'process_completed.html' );
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    }
?>
```

Comment: is your path is correct? [check this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) it will help you

Comment: The path is correct. The script send the html template but without css (the include of the bootsrap library)

Comment: You're putting the entire bootstrap CSS into an email?! You do know that email clients do not fetch external style sheets? To make this work you would have to include the CSS inside `process_completed.html` - you've not shown your code for the generation of the body, which seems to be what this question is about. BTW, if you load the autoloader (as you are), you don't need to load PHPMailer class too - the autoloader will do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$mail->SMTPSecure       = 'tsl';
```

should probably be:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure       = 'tls';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any external css files in the email template will not work.

Use only inline css in email template.

Answer (score 0):

Many email clients don't render CSS that's in the head of email HTML. You'll either need to inline the CSS before you submit the email to Mandrill, or use Mandrill's [CSS inlining option](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/24460141-Does-Mandrill-inline-CSS-automatically-).

Answer (score 0):

I made a template with inline css an it works. Thanks.